# github через ssh в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, github

```
git push -u origin master
Bad owner or permissions on /home/alex/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

sudo nano /home/alex/.ssh/config 
HOST localhost
HostName localhost
```

Мои действия:

```
sudo apt-get install git-repo
```

На странице https://github.com/settings/keys добавил "New SSH key" 
Title:"ggshaman888" Key:"содержание файла ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

На странице https://github.com/ggshaman888/work_experience/settings в поле "Source
Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch. Learn more." выбрал "master branch"

```
cd ~/folder_project
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git
git remote -v show
origin  git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git (push)
git config --global user.email "gg.shaman888@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "ggshaman888"
git commit -m "reinitial commit"
```

Comment: убедитесь, что файл `~/.ssh/config` 644 или 600 доступ имеет (chmod), а сама ~/.ssh директория —700 (последнее опционально) [ssh returns "Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config"](https://serverfault.com/q/253313/3933)

Comment: @jfs chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config вроде помогло, теперь просит ввести пароль. Посмотрим что будет дальше.

Comment: @jfs обновил вопрос, проблема осталась

Comment: `Bad owner or permissions on /home/alex/.ssh/config` проблема ушла. Появилась другая у вас проблема (`Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally.`). Старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться.

Comment: @jfs стараюсь, однако хотелось бы сделать один раз и обращаться к странице, если снова на те же грабли нарвусь.

Comment: никто, в том числе и вы не хочет простыню читать с кучей случайных команд, в надежде наскрести решение. Люди могут иметь первую ошибку, не имея второй. И наоборот, у людей может быть вторая ошибка, не имея первой.

Comment: @jfs согласен, оформите ответ, я его зачту, остальное засуну в собственный ответ, что бы не потерялось. Может не совсем корректно, за то может помочь в будущем.

Comment: первой команды: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` в вашем ответе достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

за решение благодарю @jfs

```
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

Далее сводные проблемы:

частично помогло, но пароль был забыт

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

сгенерировал новый:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mail@gmail.com"
```

повторил пункты выше...

```
git push origin master
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**UPD: 2**

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa)

git push origin master
To git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**UPD: 3**

```
git pull
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

**Решено:**

```
git pull origin master
From github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .gitignore | 39 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 LICENSE    | 21 +++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 60 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 LICENSE

git push origin master
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 46.92 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 31 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To git@github.com:ggshaman888/work_experience.git
   ba02c8e..5770637  master -> master
```